# What type of tires have tubes inside?

Tags: tire, innertube, tubeless

Don't judge me as stupid just yet, I'm not sure if mine's a tubular or tubeless tire but everyone says tubular tires are glued to the metal wheel. However, mine isn't. It consists of a smooth, inflatable tube inside, covered by a rough, durable cover. There is absolutely no glue used so I'm pretty confused. The way it stays on the wheel is because the wheel has a rim that keeps it from falling off. If it helps, by bike is a GMC Denali with 700C wheels. Please help, I really have no idea.

Comment: It sounds like you are running tubular tires on a clincher wheel. If so, this is probably not that safe. Pictures of both (with tire off of rim)?

Comment: It sounds to me like you have what is commonly (though somewhat mistakenly) referred to as a "clincher" -- the upper-left picture in James's answer.  This is the most common style by far -- probably 99% of the bikes in the US use this style.

Comment: Since your tires have no adhesive, you aren't using tubulars. Your bike uses a fairly basic 700c clincher tire, with an inner tube.

Answer (score 4):

A normal clincher tyre will have a "bead" as shown in the following diagram.[image]

It's possible you have a "tubalar clincher" like this:
[image]

If none of those quite look right, could you provide a photo?

Comment: The other possibility, of course, is tubeless -- basically the first picture but with no tube inside (but probably some sealing goo).

Comment: The GMC Denalli is avialable at [Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/GMC-Denali-700c-Men-s-Road-Bike-Large/12080282), and I am therefore 120% sure it's using clinchers.

Comment: @Kibbee ...and indeed if you look at the Walmart link, in the Q & A section, there are Qs and As that all but confirm this (talking about innertubes etc.) although I didn't explicitly see the word "clincher" anywhere.

Comment: The Tufo tubular clinchers are objectively the worst tire on the planet. Replacing stock WalMart tires with those would be a downgrade. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Jm2: Speaking as someone who's been riding the Tufo C Elite Jet tubular clincher for almost 2 years now, I'd fairly strongly disagree with that evaluation. I am curious why you make it though.

Comment: FWIW, historically a "clincher" was a tire/rim combo where the rim had J-shaped hook cross-section on the edge of the rim, and the tire had a corresponding J-shaped edge molded in, with no wire bead.  Thus the two "clinched" each other.  However, the term "clincher" has come to mean the modern wire-bead tire.

Comment: Also, in the past "tubulars" were often referred to as "sew-ons" or "sew-ups", since to repair one you'd open up the stitching on the inside diameter, extract the tube, patch it, then sew the casing back together.